# Replacement for auditd in OpenVZ

Tags: openvz, linux-audit, proxmox

Are there any replacements for auditd to use in OpenVZ containers?

ProxMox VE (pve-manager/3.4-6/102d4547 (running kernel: 2.6.32-39-pve)